# My image isnt working properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, constraints

I made the page 600 Width and 1000 Height so it runs on all iPhones, in the 'View Controller' I added a 'Scroll View', Pin it and then 'View" and Pin it, then I added an image there to be on the 'top center' .. the thing is, it shows in the picture how it is (Portrait and Landscape), I tried "Resolve Auto Layout Issue > Add Missing Constraints" to that image but still the same thing.
The 'Scroll View' works alright but the 'View' looks bigger than the iPhone screen and all the same with the iPhones
Help :)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFP4d.jpg)

Comment: Can you add image, which constraints have you used? And why scrollview? Even right constraints can solve your problem without scrollview.

Comment: It's added as a white circle, the Scroll View is needed because the height of the page is long. The constraints for the Scroll View in the pin is the four directions, the View is also in pin the four directions and the image is "Resolve Auto Layout Issue > Add Missing Constraints".. unless I didn't understand well.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add constraints to specifically set the height and width of the image view. Or else something equivalent, like constraining the height and the aspect ratio.

Every view has an idea of its intrinsic content size, and that affects how it gets laid out. The intrinsic size is how big it "wants" to be to show its contents. An image view's intrinsic size is the same as the image it's displaying, so if possible, it's going to be big enough to show the image at full size. But setting height and width constraints overrides the intrinsic size, so you get the size you want instead of the intrinsic size the image view wants.